# WSO2 API manager 2.0.0 : Swagger Model displays HTML source instead of the expected model

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When u go to APIS > API Console > Data Type > Model, you see some HTML source full of "`<span>`, `<td>`, ..." instead of the expected formatted model.

The reason seems to be the content of `<div class="description>...</div>` is between quotes (").

There is no such problem in Swagger UI (v2.2.4), the problem is caused by the version used by WSO2 API Manager or by the encapsulation done.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Could you please create a JIRA in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER?

Comment: Sure, if you create me an account. Otherwise, I suggest u submit it yourself with a high priority. I know Swagger upgrade is already planned for apim v2.1.0 but it's not certain it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduce the issue in [API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) (hosted version of API Manager) and [created the JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5493).

Comment: The correction impacts only one line of swagger-ui.js, it can be upgraded without upgrading the full release.